# Time/Date grep for 15 mins

Tags: grep, awk

I need to `grep` a specific type of line in a specific time of the log, do you have any ideas?

Here's my working script:

```
cat *.log |grep -E '2011-06-30 (1[0-1]:[0-1][0-5]|10:16)'| grep -ach '0110 478655 ..  51' * | awk '{SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'
```

The above line is working for 00:00-00:16 time. I need to sum all the `grep` results for that specific time. How do I `grep` the string:

```
00:15-00:31, 00:30-00:46, 00:45-01:01
```

Note that the time should be variable as well, meaning it won't be always 00:00-01:01 - is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can match times with a regular expression, but it's not the best tool for the job. Put all the logic into awk and perform numeric comparisons.

Awk doesn't have specific facilities for manipulating dates. GNU awk offers `mktime` and `strftime` as an extension. For the problem as specified, you don't need these extensions, but they might come in handy if your requirements grow more complex.

The “working” script you give is probably not what you meant to write: your second `grep` call has file names as arguments (`*`), so it won't read from its standard input. And you don't show sample input either. So I don't know what your requirements are.

Here's some example code that assumes that all log lines begin with a date, and that you want to sum the numbers that appear at the end of the matching lines in all log files. Pass the date in the `year`, `month` and `day` variables and the starting time in `hour` and `minute`; the snippet looks for log entries in a 15-minute range that isn't allowed to span to a different day.

```
awk -vyear=2011 -vmonth=6 -vday=30 -vhour=0 -vminute=15 -vRS='[-: ]+' '
BEGIN {start = hour * 60 + min; stop = start + 15}
{time = $4 * 60 + $5}
$1==day && $2== month && $3==day && start <= time && time <= stop && $NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
    sum += $NF
}
END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, i would like to retell the whole situation.

Comment: Hi Gilles, i would like to retell the whole situation. I wanted to grep something withing that specific time frame, `grep -E 'Jul  1 (04:[0-1][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]|04:20:00)'` will output the specified time i wanted, now my problem is how can i grep something within that specific time, i wanted  to execute this line `grep -ach '0110 478655 ..  51' * | awk '{SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'` for that time range, currently just mixing the time grep and the sum grep nothing will output 0 instead.

Comment: without the time frame, 'grep -ach '0110 478655 .. 51' * | awk '{SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'*` will give me an output of 40, while `grep -E 'Jul  1 (01:[2-3][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]|01:40:00)' | grep -ach '0110 478655 ..  51' | awk '{SUM += $1} END { print SUM }'*` will output 0, (which is supposedly 2)

Comment: @afbr Whoa! Edit your question. Express your requirements in words, and add some sample input and output.

Comment: Haha! :3 Sorry for the all the confusion.. ok here: 
i wanted to count 'foo' on a folder with tons of logs and sum all the 'foo' for a specific time frame. 
example :
range 00:15-00:31, grep -c 'foo' then sum it all.